# Put a lot of pictures together to make one picture, how to use the picture which you want

Tags: css, css-sprites

Recently i heard about css sprite is a good technology, can reduce the browser downloads, faster web speeds,  how does it achieve ?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ - use the google

Answer (score 0):

check this out it will help you alot... 
http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

also this for techniques...
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/